# S3 responses 403 right after upload

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use `aws-java-sdk-bom` in order to upload file:

```
final PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, blobKey.toString(), input, metadata);
putRequest.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

final ProgressTracker progress = new ProgressTracker();
transferManager.upload(putRequest, new S3ProgressListenerChain(progress));
```

and I noticed that sometimes if I try to access the URL right after the request is successfully done (mostly for big >20Mb files) it responses with 403.. After a second - everything is OK. Is there any timeout or something?

Comment: Did you do anything to the (future) object before the upload?  If you tried to download or get metadata on the object (to check whether it existed, perhaps) before the upload, this behavior would be expected, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should ref to the AWS S3 FAQ, I believe it takes little time to propogate...

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel